# chart.js Dynamically align grid lines with multiple y-axis

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

When I generate a chart with multiple y-axis the grid lines on the y-axis don't align, because the tick count on the left is higher than on the right.

[image]

What I want to achieve:
[image]

However I had to specify the tick count:

```
  this.chartOptions!.scales!.y!.ticks = {
    count: 9
  }
  this.chartOptions!.scales!.y1!.ticks = {
    count: 9
  }
```

But I don't want the count always to be 9. What I want is incase the left tick count equals 9 and the right equals 7 by default then I want both y-axis to have a tick count of 9 and if the right tick count equals 7 and the left equals 6 by default then I want both y-axis to have a tick count of 7. How do I achieve this with Chart.js?